# git cherry-pick throws "a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress"

Tags: git

I have range of commits, first is older than the second.
When I try to cherry-pick this range I get error:

[image]

I dont understand why it does not work...

Comment: What if you first try what the hint suggests, `git cherry-pick --abort`? Does that work?

Comment: If your Git is relatively recent, `git status` should tell you that you already have an existing cherry-pick in progress. You must finish that one, or terminate it, to start a new one.

Comment: Hmm, thanks `git cherry-pick --abort` indeed helped, the one thing I dont understand is that git status was NOT telling me that any cherry-pick is in progress - weird. Also after `git cherry-pick --abort` I got message "warning: You seem to have moved HEAD. Not rewinding, check your HEAD!". Anyway it worked. Thanks!